# Pytesting a script that is not a library

Tags: python, pytest

I have the following directory structure

```
|
|---test
|    |----test1.py
|    |----test2.py
|
|---alibrary
|    |--thelib.py
|
|
|--main.py
```

In `test1.py` I tested the functions in `thelib.py`.
To do this, the script started like this

```
import alibrary.thelib as thelib

#and in some other part
thelib.some_function()
```

It worked well.
Now I have to write `test2.py` in which I have to test some functions that are written in `main.py`

Since `main.py` is in a level above the testing code which is the correct way I can include `main.py` so that I can test its functions? (Ideally without altering the `sys path`)

Comment: you should add and `__init__.py` file to both the test directory and alibrary directiory.  Then in test2.py you can just use `import main` as long as you are running the tests from the top root directory

Comment: interesting. I did an experiment and it run from the top root directory even though I did not add `__init__py` yet. But it did not run from inside the test directory. (which is ok as far as it is running from outside)

Comment: The `__init__.py` isn't strictly necessary unless you are importing within the the same directory, but it is still go practice to include it.  Especially if you plan on expanding your app. once you start adding pytest fixtures that you might want to share between testing modules it will be necessary